# Explicit isomorphism $\pi_{n+1}(\mathbb{RP}^n) \cong \pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^{n-1})$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, projective-space, higher-homotopy-groups

From covering space theory we know that $\pi_{n+1}(\mathbb{RP}^n) \cong \pi_{n+1}(\mathbb{S}^n)$.

From wikipedia I can notice that $\pi_{n+1}(\mathbb{S}^n) \cong \pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^{n-1})$.*

My question is: is there an explicit isomorphism $\pi_{n+1}(\mathbb{RP}^n) \cong \pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^{n-1})$? My question is also motivated by the fact that $\mathbb{RP}^n \cong \mathbb{R}^n \cup \mathbb{RP}^{n-1}$ and $I^{n+1} = I^n \times I$ with $\mathring{I^n} \cong \mathbb{R}^n$.

*I "know" the standard calculation of $\pi_{n+1}(\mathbb{S}^n)$, for example via Pontryagin construction or $J$-homomorphism. I was wondering if it's possible to compute it in the way I stated.

Comment: Well, both groups are $\Bbb Z/2$ and there's only one isomorphism between them, so in some sense it is explicit. But I think there cannot be any isomorphism of topological nature between them: odd dimensional projective space is a particular example of a lens space $S^{2k+1}/(\Bbb Z/n)$, and if some construction worked for one of them it will at least at some extent work for others.